# Añadamos información relevante como comentario de las ediciones

Tags: discusión, ediciones

Hoy, como muchos otros días, acabo de encontrarme con una [sugerencia de edición](https://es.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/79743) en la que el comentario dice:

> Cambiando etiquetas:
>
> [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y efectivamente, así es:

> [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Sin embargo, **la página ya se encarga de decirme que se están cambiando las etiquetas**. Y de una forma muy gráfica y fácil de entender.

Las preguntas relevantes para un revisor de edición son:

- ¿Por qué se está cambiando algo?
- ¿En qué hace mejor la pregunta?
- ¿Por qué estas nuevas etiquetas compartimentan mejor la pregunta?

Y nada de eso se explica por lo que no me queda más remedio que juzgar el tema desde cero si se quiere saber si vale la pena el cambio.

Por ello, animo a todos los que utilizan las sugerencias de edición a que complementen su espléndido trabajo facilitando la vida de los revisores. ¿Cómo? Pues muy fácil: añadiendo una descripción apropiada.

Esto también aplica a quien revisa una publicación directamente, pues ya tiene el privilegio. Es bueno explicar por qué se hizo algo, para que sea más fácil entender en caso que el qué no sea trivial.

Como nota mental yo diría: **los comentarios en las revisiones deberían ser como los que hacemos en el código y describir el porqué y no el qué**.

Comment: Confieso que he pecado