# Ediciones para corregir la indentación en Python

Tags: discusión, ediciones, ediciones-sugeridas, colas-de-revisión

Soy nuevo en esta comunidad (aunque viejo en las de stackoverflow en inglés, y en particular en la de tex). Por tanto todavía no tengo permisos para editar preguntas sin que pasen por una cola de revisión.

Recientemente he editado un par de preguntas en las que el autor pegaba código python, pero a la hora de convertirlo a código markdown no indentaba correctamente todo el contenido. Como consecuencia, líneas que deberían estar indentadas no lo estaban, y ya que en python la indentación es parte de la sintaxis (es el delimitador de bloque, python no tiene llaves para esto), con la indentación incorrecta el programa bien pasa a ser erróneo o bien a cambiar por completo el significado.

Para mi sorpresa en ambas ediciones he recibido votos en contra por parte de los revisores, con la explicación de que:

> Esta edición no contribuye a que la publicación sea ni siquiera un poco más fácil de leer, más fácil de encontrar, más precisa o más accesible. Los cambios implementados son completamente superfluos o perjudican activamente la lectura.

Casos:

1. https://es.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/83870
2. https://es.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/83990

Naturalmente estoy en desacuerdo con esa apreciación, ya que en el caso de python, la indentación no es una mera cuestión estética.

El caso es que sospecho que los editores que votaron en contra no tienen experiencia con python (sospecha que se confirma viendo su lista de tags activos).

En mi caso, he insistido con la edición de la pregunta y he añadido en los comentarios a la edición por qué la indentación es relevante. Poco después las ediciones fueron admitidas. Quizás otro usuario menos insistente que yo abandone la edición de esa pregunta o de otras similares, perdiéndose así la oportunidad de mejorar el sitio.

Sólo quería dejar constancia de este problema. Quizás se podría hacer algo más para disminuir la probabilidad de que un revisor vote en contra de este tipo de ediciones, pero no se me ocurre qué. Quizás aclarar algo en los mensajes predefinidos para el rechazo de ediciones, pero no veo bien cómo articularlo para que a la vez que el mensaje es genérico, incluya advertencias específicas para python.

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo en lo que comentas y es una pena que una sugerencia de edición de este tipo se rechace. Sin embargo, mirando [tus sugerencias](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/7123/jldiaz?tab=activity&sort=suggestions) apenas veo una rechazada: [esta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/83990), que si bien era correctísima, podía inducir a despiste pues para alguien no muy ducho en la materia parecería que estos getters y setters no son de la clase `Colonia`. Nótese además que la segunda adición de espacios, en `def empezar(self)` era probablemente innecesaria.

Comment: Yo fuí uno de los que rechazo al menos una de tus ediciones, y asumo mi culpa. Efectivamente, aunque no soy experto en Python, si conocía que la indentación es importante, pero a veces algo se nos escapa. Por supuesto, lo que has hecho es lo correcto. Este post nos da un toque de atención a los revisores, y de esta manera espero que no vuelva a suceder.

Comment: @fedorqui He hecho sólo tres ediciones de este tipo. Una fue rechazada inicialmente, pero insistí y a la segunda fue aceptada. Las otras fueron aceptadas, pero mirando las votaciones de los revisores encontré que alguno de ellos había votado en contra por la razón indicada. Por eso he decidido comentarlo aqui

Comment: @Pikoh Gracias. No buscaba disculpas ni nada parecido, sino lo que tú bien dices: un toque de atención. Como digo, a mi no me ha importado insistir, pero quizás otros más primerizos puedan sentirse decepcionados y abandonen.

Comment: Por supuesto, y asi me lo tomo. A veces en lenguajes que no dominas,es fácil cometer esos errores. Por mi parte, lección aprendida y trataré de estar mas atento a esas cosas.

Comment: Añado: de hecho el caso ha sido bien curioso. Tus dos sugerencias ([la primera](https://es.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/83870) y [la segunda](https://es.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/83990)) fueron rechazadas, pero luego el OP aceptó la primera. Además, en la 2.ª hiciste bien al indicar el motivo de insistir en esa sugerencia. ¡Bien hecho! Los revisores deberían haber estado más atentos al comentario.

Comment: @JLDiaz puedes llevar el tema al [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30872/stack-overflow-en-espanol), y a lo mejor el tema podría ser discutido un tanto más directo ;)

Comment: @fedorqui bueno, yo solo rechacé una, pero efectivamente debi haber estado mas atento. Como digo, es un lenguaje que no domino. Pero de todas maneras hay que decir que por esa razón las revisiones no son aprobadas o rechazadas por una sola persona. Este caso se ha escapado, pero lo normal es que aunque un revisor se equivoque, otros lo aprueben

Comment: @Pikoh claro, ¡sin problema! Y lo bueno de Stack Exchange es que todo queda registrado y puedes señalar con el dedo... digo... recuperar estas sugerencias de edición y aprender de ellas.

Comment: @JLDiaz, el tema de la edición de código es un tema que a mí al menos me resulta complicado, en tu caso, la edición me resulta claramente apropiada y si si la hubiera votado posiblemente la aprobaría, pero soy de la idea que el código lo debería tocar solamente el OP, salvo contadísimas excepciones.

Comment: @PatricioMoracho De acuerdo en que la forma en que cada cual formatea su código es muy personal, y en eso no entraría. Asimismo, si el código contiene un error y esa es precisamente la razón por la que se plantea la pregunta, no habría que corregir ese error, sino responder indicando dónde está. Sin embargo, en los casos en que el error es claramente tipográfico y no relacionado con lo que se pregunta, corregirlo puede ayudar a quienes intenten responder, ahorrándoles el tiempo de tener que arreglarlo ellos. Coincido que es un tema delicado.

Answer (score 7):

Tus sugerencias estaban perfectas en ambos casos, y me parece genial que traigas esta advertencia a Meta. También agrego que conviene ser un poco más explícito en el motivo de la sugerencia.

Justamente porque es Python, hay que tener muchísimo cuidado al corregir la indentación. Si fuese otro lenguaje, y una sugerencia de edición hace (incluso sutilmente) que sea más sencillo leer la pregunta al indentar el código de otra forma, lo apruebo sin pensarlo dos veces.

Pero en Python, hay que estar completamente seguro de que **el error de la pregunta no es debido a una mala indentación**. Por ejemplo, si el error que está teniendo el autor fuese por una mala indentación, estarías escondiendo el error que tiene (y nadie podría encontrar cuál es el error para responderle).

Recuerdo revisar tu sugerencia en: https://es.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/83870, y estuve a punto de rechazarla. No había ningún indicativo de que la pregunta no fuese por un error de indentación, no había ningún comentario en el que el autor aceptara que fue un error al copiar y pegar, y no había un mensaje de error "claro" que ayude a determinar que el intérprete había pasado ese punto sin marcar errores.

Para examinar mejor, abrí la pregunta en otra pestaña, vi que tenía una respuesta aceptada, y que la respuesta trataba sobre un error que puede surgir y solucionarse únicamente si el autor tenía bien indentado el código pero lo copió mal. Recién ahí voté por aprobar tu sugerencia.

Ahora, esto requiere examinar con mucho detalle tu sugerencia, algo que no siempre un revisor tiene tiempo o capacidad para hacer, dando lugar a algunos ejemplos no deseados donde se hacen las cosas sin analizar correctamente. En estos casos, quizás ayude un comentario en el **motivo de la edición**, algo del estilo (o similar) a

> *Indentación - fue error al copiar - se demuestra en la respuesta aceptada que es otro el error*

Esto es algo que pedimos frecuentemente, y está mejor explicado en *[Añadamos información relevante como comentario de las ediciones](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3052/127)*.

O, mucho mejor aún, un **comentario previo** debajo de la pregunta que mencione algo de esto. Consultarle al autor si lo tiene bien indentado en su código, pero lo copió mal, hubiese sido ideal.

Además, también hay que tener cuidado en lenguajes donde el estilo juega un papel importante en la *belleza* del código: se me ocurren R o Go, aunque Python tiene gran parte de esto con código más [***pythonic***](https://blog.startifact.com/posts/older/what-is-pythonic.html). En estos casos, cambiarle el estilo al autor podría hacer que se vea diferente a su intención original.

Comment: @Flxtr tomé tu comentario, incluí una parte y adapté la otra

Answer (score 1):

Hoy topé con otra sugerencia de edición tuya y la rechacé. Te dejé un comentario, pero lo publico aquí como respuesta para asegurarme que te llegue y, quién sabe, para explicar algo que puede ayudar a otros :)

Lo que [dije](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/143705/mostrar-informacion-de-un-arbol-binario-de-busqueda-python#comment269761_143705):

> @abulafia rechacé tu [sugerencia de edición](https://es.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/86501) porque añadías lenguaje para coloreado sintáctico cuando esta ya está definida en [es.stackoverflow.com/tags/python-3.x/info](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tags/python-3.x/info). Además, la añadías mal (es `language: lang-python`). Finalmente, es interesante indicar que puedes usar `language-all: lang-python` para que aplique a todos los grupos, en lugar de añadir la sentencia en cada uno de ellos.

Explico cada cosa:

Como se explica en [¿Qué es el resaltado de sintaxis? ¿Cómo funciona?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1463/83), una etiqueta dada puede tener un *coloreado* sintáctico predeterminado para que todas las publicaciones lo usen por defecto. En efecto, esto ocurre con [python-3.x](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-3.x), como se ve en la [página de info de la etiqueta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tags/python-3.x/info), donde se lee:

> Lenguaje de código (utilizado para [resaltar la sintaxis](https://github.com/google/code-prettify)): lang-py

Por tanto, dada una publicación cualquiera, no es necesario añadir porque no está aportando nada. (Aquí es cuando paramos y [agradecemos enormemente a lois6b por añadir todos los códigos y a Mariano por recopilarlos](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1840/un-poco-m%C3%A1s-de-color-para-soes-en-el-c%C3%B3digo?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment9867_1841)).

<s>Además, fíjate que utilizas `language: python`, cuando la página el [listado de códigos](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1840/83) nos indica que es `language: lang-py`.</s> Lo dije mal: es correcto usar `language: python`, pues en este caso busca el resaltado de sintaxis referente a la etiqueta "python".

Finalmente, comento que no hace falta añadirlo en cada bloque. En efecto, como explica la [página de ayuda de Resaltado de sintaxis](https://es.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting), puedes usar `language-all: X` para definir el resaltado de todos los bloques en lugar de ir uno a uno.

---

Aprovecho también para felicitarte por estar usando motivos super detallados a la hora de sugerir nuevas ediciones. Paseando por [tus sugerencias](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/7123/abulafia?tab=activity) veo que ahora pones las cosas muy fáciles a quien revisa :)

Comment: Gracias por ilustrarme en aspectos que desconocía. Por ejemplo, no sabía que ciertas etiquetas implicaban automáticamente un coloreado, ni la existencia del `language-all`, que me será muy útil. No obstante el tag `language: python`, aunque oficialmente sea `lang-py`, creo que funciona igualmente. Yo al menos es el que había usado hasta ahora en todas mis respuestas y producía el resultado esperado.

Comment: Respecto de mi edición, veo un problema en que la rechazaras. Por un lado está bien porque te ha dado la oportunidad de explicar estas cosas, pero por otro, rechazar la edición implicaba no sólo los detalles del coloreado sintáctico, sino también la indentación del código que esa sí era crucial pues sin ella la sintaxis era incorrecta. Es un problema cuando en una misma edición se juntan aspectos cruciales como el indentado con otros más superfluos como el coloreado. En tu caso yo habría aceptado la edición, pues lo del colorado al final tampoco hacía ningún mal y no era visible.

Comment: @abulafia respecto rechazar, podría haber aceptado (lo pensé) en tal caso difícilmente te habrías parado a revisar el motivo del rechazo, como finalmente pasó porque se aprobó. Es cierto que identar los métodos de la clase `Tipo_Inversion` es necesario, pero no se perdía demasiado trabajo rechazándola y era fácil de volver a sugerir.

Comment: @abulafia tienes razón, sí que funciona `language: python`. Hice [una prueba](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3249/83) y al hilo surgió un debate con Mariano en que me hizo ver que sí, que `language: X` coge la sintaxis de la etiqueta X. He editado la respuesta.

Comment: En esos casos (creo, por cierto, que yo aprobé esa edición) lo que yo suelo hacer es "Mejorar edición" en lugar de rechazarla. De esa manera, no se pierde lo bueno de la edición y se modifica lo que esté mal

Comment: En cuanto a `language: x`, creo que depende de los casos. Al menos, antes con `vb.net` no funcionaba (no se si ya se solucionó el problema)

Comment: @Pikoh toma el lenguaje definido para la etiqueta... El problema es que antes la etiqueta no tenía nada definido (a menos que estés hablando de un problema con el punto del que no tengo idea)

Comment: No @Mariano, me refiero a que a veces hay lenguajes que no tienen highlightning definido. Pongo el ejemplo de vb.net porque es el que conozco, en numerosas ocasiones tengo que editar preguntas/respuestas para poner `lang-vb` ya que si no, no lo hace correctamente

Comment: @Pikoh entonces deberías hacer un ping a lois6b y solicitar que se añadan lenguajes a [la lista](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1841/83).

Comment: @Pikoh entiendo... Habría que ver el caso, pero me imagino que es porque tiene otra etiqueta (que le gana en cantidad de preguntas)... No obstante, `lang: vb.net` debería funcionar (pero no hay motivo para usarlo, preferible cómo estás haciendo

Comment: fedorqui, segun esa lista vb.net ya está configurado :) Ahora la verdad no recuerdo si el problema es cuando hay mas de una etiqueta, es posible que sea eso...

Comment: @abulafia Yo hubiese rechazado la sugerencia de edición, pero por un motivo completamente diferente... Se está corrigiendo un problema de indentación (especialmente en `def ArbolBusqueda`), pero el autor publicó el código bien indentado, por lo que asumo que ese problema lo tiene en su código original... Esto es parte de lo que mencionaba [en mi respuesta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3197/127)

Comment: @Mariano Si, pero no. El error no estaba en el código original del usuario, pues no reportaba ninguna excepción por `SyntaxError`, sino otro problema. El autor publicó el código indentado, pero mal. Esto ocurre muy a menudo al pegar código python. Ya que típicamente en python se tiene una primera línea con `def` o `class` y luego el resto del código (cuerpo de la función o clase) va metido cuatro espacios, el bloque es tomado por markdown válido y formateado como código, pero no la primera línea con la cabecera (sigue...)

Comment: @Mariano En algunos casos el usuario no se da cuenta de que esa primera línea ha quedado mal y lo deja así (he visto muchos ejemplos). En otros casos el usuario se da cuenta, y edita su pregunta para marcar esa primera línea como código, pulsando el botón `{}`, con lo que esa línea es indentada cuatro espacios. El problema es que entonces queda indentada al mismo nivel que el cuerpo de la función o clase. Aunque todo queda marcado como código, la indentación es sintácticamente incorrecta. No sé si me he explicado.

Comment: @Mariano He encontrado muchos ejemplos de código así. De hecho son la mayoría de los que he editado, y cuyas ediciones en algunos casos se me han rechazado aduciendo razones como la tuya (que la falta de indentación no es un error, sino que ya estaba originalmente así). Opino que en la gran mayoría de casos no es así, puesto que el usuario entonces estaría preguntando cuál es el error de sintaxis, en lugar de preguntar por qué no imprime el programa lo que debería, etc.

Comment: @abulafia entiendo, y lo más probable es que sea como estás diciendo. Sé que ocurre constantemente y la culpa es del mal editor/formateador de código de SO, no del autor de la pregunta. Sin embargo, por más que sea casi evidente que fue un error al pegar, estoy convencido de que no conviene arreglárselo así porque (1) siempre hay un pequeño margen de error y podría ser un problema de indentación que no de SyntaxError y (2) tienen que aprender en algún momento a usar el `{ }` y revisar la pregunta antes de publicar

Comment: @Mariano Por desgracia muchos casos son de personas que hacen su pregunta y nunca más vuelven a mirarla, una vez han recibido su respuesta. Dejarlo "mal" sólo sirve para que futuros lectores tengan más difícil leerlo. Entiendo que precisamente para esto están las ediciones de la comunidad. En fin, parece que no estamos de acuerdo en este punto. Yo seguiré corrigiendo los que vea evidente que fue un fallo de pegado, y tú puedes seguir votando en contra de mis ediciones :-)

Comment: @abulafia ok. En este caso en particular, la pregunta la hizo ayer. Yo intentaría dejar un comentario preguntando si fue error al pegar y pidiendo que lo arregle... Si fuese una pregunta muerta, no lo veo tan mal... Y no quiero que se malentienda, estoy convencido de que tus ediciones son para mejorar la calidad del sitio, y eso está genial, sólo difiero en casos muy puntuales (así como en mi respuesta había dicho que *esas* ediciones estaban perfectas).

Comment: @abulafia sí, veo también muchos casos de que no se dan cuenta de que la primera línea quedó mal ([ejemplo de ahora mismo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/86589), con SQL).

Comment: @Mariano gracias por hacerme ver lo de las etiquetas. He actualizado la traducción de [¿Qué es el resaltado de sintaxis? ¿Cómo funciona?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1464/83) para incluir esta parte, que en su momento omití unilateralmente.